# Нужно получить и сложить value с input на чистом JS

Tags: javascript

Задача: даны два инпута, кнопка и абзац. В инпуты вводятся числа. По нажатию на кнопку запишите сумму чисел в абзац.

Вот мой не рабочий код:

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = t2 = () => {

  let poleOne = document.querySelector('.poleOne')
  let poleTwoo = document.querySelector('.poleTwoo')
  let sum = poleOne.value + poleTwoo.value
  document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = sum;

}
```

```html
    <input type="number" name="" id="poleOne">
    <input type="number" name="" id="poleTwoo">
    <button class="btn">Результат:</button>
    <p class="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас указан `id`, а используете класс.

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = () => {
  const poleOne = document.querySelector('#poleOne');
  const poleTwoo = document.querySelector('#poleTwoo');
  const sum = +poleOne.value + +poleTwoo.value;
  document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="" id="poleOne">
<input type="number" name="" id="poleTwoo">
<button class="btn">Результат:</button>
<p class="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = t2 = () => {

  let poleOne = document.querySelector('#poleOne');
                                     // ^------- Раз
  let poleTwoo = document.querySelector('#poleTwoo');
                                      // ^------- Два
  let sum = Number.parseInt(poleOne.value, 10) + Number.parseInt(poleTwoo.value, 10);
         // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Три 
  document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="" id="poleOne">
    <input type="number" name="" id="poleTwoo">
    <button class="btn">Результат:</button>
    <p class="result"></p>
```